# how to ignore json object in objects array which has mandatory field null

Tags: json, swift, object, null

I have a JSON which looks like this:

```
     "Ur" : [
    {
      "****" : null,
      "id" : "Pati_test142$2003-11$1584460784000",
      "******" : true,
      "ClientLocalDate" : "2020-03-17T18:17:27+02:00",
      "file_raw" : false,
      "doing" : null,
      "_id" : "******",
      "When" : "2020-03-17T17:59:44+02:00",
      "DateUTC" : "2020-03-17T16:17:30.513Z",
      "***" : false,
      "Leak" : null,
      "******" : true
    },
    {
      "FeelUrge" : null,
      "id" : "Pati_test142$2003-11$1584460957000",
      "******" : true,
      "ClientLocalDate" : "2020-03-17T18:17:27+02:00",
      "file_raw" : false,
      "doing" : null,
      "_id" : "******",
      "When" : "2020-03-17T17:59:44+02:00",
      "DateUTC" : "2020-03-17T16:17:30.901Z",
      "***" : false,
      "Leak" : null,
      "******" : true
    }]
```

"When" is a mandatory field, How can I ignore objects in JSON array which has null value in this field?
There must be a way to do it in the decoder

Comment: This looks like invalid JSON. Also, please fix the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following init method for decoding where first the array is decoded into an local variable and then the result of filtering the array for non-nil values is assigned the property.

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let array = try container.decode([UrElement].self, forKey: .ur)
    ur = array.filter{ $0.when != nil }
}
```